# wp_nav_menu: indicate by id page grandparents

Tags: menus, navigation

I have an web site with top-header menu and sidebar menu.

Situation, like:

header menu: books **music** movies (if we are now under music)

sidemenu: blues **jazz** dance (if we are now under "Jazz")

sidemenu submenu (under jazz): 60's **90's** 40's (if we are now at 90's)

I would like to know how can I highlight MUSIC item from top menu (for example by id or class), because wp_nav_menu does't mark this grandparent item in any way...

Please, help!! )

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a class to the correct menu item yourself. Here is a similar example which you can modify according to your needs: http://wpthemetutorial.com/2013/05/14/filtering-classes-on-wp_nav_menu/